# Wordpress is blocking bootstrap collapse?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu

I am building two websites using the same design with Bootstrap

The first one (A) does not have wordpress: http://biomedic.isr.ist.utl.pt

Se second one (B) has wordpress behind it: http://healthnmoney.com/david/LBA

The problem is the dropdown menu in the mobile version (the "hamburguer" dropdown menu). On A it works fine, on B it does not close

```
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
     class="navbar-collapse collapse in"
     aria-expanded="false"
     style=""> ... </div>
```

In the A version the aria-expanded, is not set. In the B version the "in" class is not removed when it is supposed to. Also when collapsing, the height should be set to 1px, and it's not.

I really appreciate any help on this.

WP: 4.0.1
Jquery: 1.11
Boots: 3.2.0

Comment: in the second case, wordpress insert jquery and bootstrap libraries in the header and they're also included in the footer. That means you include both libraries twice, and that cause problems

Comment: Wow. So simple. That solves it. The included jQuery (1.11.1) in Wordpress does not work with my code made in 1.11.0. I'm wondering if it is wise to wp_deregister_script('jquery'); in the functions.php?